# Closet thing to an Euler circuit over a hypercube of odd integer dimension?

Tags: graph-theory

Every hyper cube of dimension N, where N is an even positive integer, has Euler circuits.
The question is, for the case of the hypercubes of odd dimension, do there exist "double Euler circuits", where we define "double Euler circuit" as a circuit that traverses each edge exactly two times, arriving, as circuits do, at the starting point after doing the traversing?

And if not, what is the minimum number of edges that must be retraced in a circuit covering all the edges, traversing each edge only one or two times in a hypercube of odd dimension? (Thus relaxing the Euler circuit requirement by allowing at most two, instead of one, traversals of any particular edge, but still requiring all edges to be traversed at least once.)

I herein claim that such a minimum is less than half of the edges of the even hypercube of N+1.

But what is that minimum as a function of ((N+1)/2)?

Comment: I changed my "picture", "icon", or whatever to a figure I generated with a program that can draw a hyper cube of any dimension with no pen lift, including odd dimensions.  This one is 6d and colored by Inkscape which also generated this .png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'yes' and you can use the fact that even-dimensional hypercubes have Euler circuits.

Eacht $2n + 1$-dimensional cube can be seen as two $2n$-dimensional cubes $ABC...Z$ and $A'B'C'...Z'$ with extra edges $AA'$, $BB'$, ..., $ZZ'$.

Now first travel through $ABCDE...Z$ in an Euler fashion, beginning and ending in $A$. Then move to $A'$. Now travel through $A'B'...Z'$ but each time you arive at a vertex of $A'B'... Z'$ for the first time, move up and down the 'extra' edge. So when you are in $B'$ the first time you move to $B$ and back to $B'$ and then continue your Euler circuit.

Now do the Euler circuit through $A'B'...Z'$ again, but without going up and down the extra edges.

Finally go back to $A$ and run through $ABCDE...Z$ again.

EDIT: above answer was for traversing every edge exactly twice, but it gives also an easy way to traverse most edges only once, simply by not doing the Euler circuits through $A'B'...Z'$ and $AB...Z$ a second time.

We see that the $N$-dimensional cube has twice the number of edges in a $N-1$-dimensional cube, plus the 'extra' edges whose number equals the number of point in an $N-1$-dimensional cube. From the above answer we see that we can have a circuit in which only these extra edges are traversed twice. Those are with $2^{N-1}$. I don't know if it is the minimum.

We can however compute this number as a fraction of half the number of edges in the $N+1$-dimensional cube (as you propose in the question). Writing $E_N$ for the number of edges in the $N$-dimensional cube we find that $E_1$ is 1 and (as I wrote above) $E_{k+1} = 2E_k + 2^{k-1}$. This gives that $E_k = k(2^{k-1})$, so $E_{N+1}/2 = (N+1)2^{N-1}$, and so the number of edges traversed twice in my construction is $1/(N+1)$th of this number. The shear niceness of this fraction gives some confidence that this is indeed the global minimum, but I am not sure.

SECOND EDIT: yes $2^{N-1}$ is indeed the minimum number of edges that needs to be traversed twice.

We can reformulate the question: instead of how many edges do we need to traverse twice, we can ask: how many extra edges do we need to draw to make the graph into one with an Euler-circuit, where we add the extra condition that new edges may only be parallel to existing edges.

Now we know since Euler that graphs have Euler circuits if and only if every vertex has even degree. An extra edge can turn at most 2 vertices with odd degree into vertices with even degree, so the number of extra edges needed is at least half of the number of vertices with odd degree.

In the odd-dimensional cube, every vertex has odd degree, so we need at least $2^{N-1}$ extra edges, or in other words: at least $2^{N-1}$ edges need to be traversed twice if we want to go through every edge at least once and at most twice. Since we already know (see first edit) that it *can* be done by traversing $2^{N-1}$ edges twice, we see that $2^{N-1}$ is indeed the minimum.

Comment: Try your construction ideas on this six -dimensional hypercube represented by this walk, where positive is going along the axis "up", and negative is going "down" the axis.  I think your idea is fine for four dimensions.  But, please add something to four and above to make it work there as well.  Thank you for your proposed answer.

Comment: Here is your clue: An Eulerian circuit is not Hamiltonian in general.. so there are too many retraces.

Comment: Please revise your answer.

Comment: [1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 1, 2, -1, -2, 4, 1, 2, -1, -2, -3, 1, -4, 3, 4, -3, 2, -4, 3, 4, -3, -1, -4, 3, 4, -3, -2, -4, 5, 1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 1, 2, -1, -2, 4, 1, 2, -1, -2, -3, 1, -4, 3, 4, -3, 2, -4, 3, 4, -3, -1, -4, 3, 4, -3, -2, -4, 6, 1, 2, -1, -2, 3, 1, 2, -1, -2, 4, 1, 2, -1, -2, -3, 1, -4, 3, 4, -3, 2, -4, 3, 4, -3, -1, -4, 3, 4, -3, -2, -4, -5, 1, 2, -1, -2, 3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 1, 2, -1, -2, 4, -6, 5, 6, -5, 1, 2, -1, -2, -3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 1, -4, -6, 5, 6, -5, 3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 4, -

Comment: (continued)6, 5, 6, -5, -3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 2, -4, -6, 5, 6, -5, 3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 4, -6, 5, 6, -5, -3, -6, 5, 6, -5, -1, -4, -6, 5, 6, -5, 3, -6, 5, 6, -5, 4, -6, 5, 6, -5, -3, -6, 5, 6, -5, -2, -4, -6]

Comment: You see, I could not post the sequence for a 6d hyper cube because it is "too long".  So, it is broken in two.

Comment: At 17 dimensions, Inkscape dies when trying to convert it to .png after coloring it in the way I set, even though the entire hypercube is a single object (an Euler Circuit).

Comment: Due to my "reputation", I am unable to vote an answer here down.  Please help.

Comment: I not sure if I understand your comments. You said that the six-dimensional cube has Euler circuits, I did not question that. My construction is then about the 7-dimensional cube which can be realized by taking two copies of the six-dimensional cube and connecting corresponding edges

Comment: We can think about the vertices of the $N$-dimensional cube as all points in $N$-dimensional space all whose coordinates are either $-1$ or $1$. Now the vertices whose $N$'th coordinate equals $-1$ (there are $2^{N-1}$ of them) together with the edges between them form a $(N-1)$-dimensional cube, I called that one $ABC...Z$. The vertices whose last coordinate equals $1$ also form a $(N-1)$-dimensional cube, I called that one $A'B'C'...Z'$. Now together the two lower-dimensional cubes cover all vertices of the $N$-dimensional cube, but not all edges....

Comment: The edges that need to be added are the ones that connect two points that have the same  first $N-1$ coordinates. (I called then AA', BB' etc). There are $2^{N-1}$ of them

Comment: aah wait, I see one thing that can be improved in this post, I will edit that

Comment: ok. you do not need to keep track of the vertices you have visited; I do not. I construct the next higher dimension Euler circuit first, in place, without recording data about which vertex visited.. then remove a dimension and simplify. your answer is pretty good though.